# Postgres.pgadmin. How to configure encoding?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, pgadmin

I have installed postgreSQL.

I use pgAdminIII as admin panel.

I am trying to watch tables content and see following:

[image: pgadmin screenshot]

How to avoid encoding problem?

Comment: What is the encoding of your database?

Comment: Just click on the database in the pgAdmin object browser. The encoding should be listed on the right.

Comment: There wrote: ** Encoding  UTF8 **

Comment: @Nick Barnes http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/141004/638c33dde3.jpg

Comment: @Nick Barnes do you have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a UTF8 database, pgAdmin should always display strings correctly. The most likely explanation is that the data itself is incorrect.

This generally happens when a client application sends data in a format which doesn't match its `client_encoding` setting. If this is the case, setting `client_encoding` correctly would prevent this from happening (provided the client application's code page is [supported by Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/multibyte.html)). This wouldn't fix the existing data, but it might be possible to repair it with the [`convert` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).

Comment: I executed it from windows cmd like this **C:\Users\redwhite>psql -U marc -d marc_db -a -f D:\sql\postgres\init.sql**

Comment: In cmd I see following VALUES (1, 6, 'Р?РчС?Р?С<Р№ С'РчС?Р?РёР?Р°Р>', '19:00', '5', 55.67834420000001,
37.79668899999999,
        35, 7, 'Р?РчС?Р?С<Р№', 0, 0, 0, 'linux',
        '9:00', 'Р?С?С?РєРёР?Р°', 'Р?РєС'РёР?РчР?', 0, 5, 9,
        1, 1, NULL, 1, 1);

Comment: What happens if you run the script from pgAdmin?

Comment: ddl(database creation) script doesn't work but insert script work properly and names are good encoded

Comment: You might just need to set psql's client encoding to match the file encoding. You can do this by running `set PGCLIENTENCODING=...` in cmd. The list of allowed encodings is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/multibyte.html).